# Can't use materilize modal?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

i have another problem with materialize,this time i try to create a modal div,and it doesn't work.The button is created,but when i click on it,nothing happend.I also link all materialize files,and  it still not working
Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,600,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">



  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
<!-- FIREBASE -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="../scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/account.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/materialize.min.js"></script>


</html> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [initialize](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#initialization) the modal:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });
```

https://materializecss.com/modals.html#initialization